# 'Settings' option for region has dissappeared

Tags: 7, theming

I am working on a Node template variant. I added a class each to the two regions (Gear icon, 'Settings' option) that make up the template: `page-left` and `page-right`. This worked well and allowed me to write my styles.

However, I've come back to it after the weekend and now one of the classes, `page-left` has dissappeared. Further more, the 'Settings' option under the Gear Icon is missing, so I cannot add the class back.

Oddly the other region, `page-right`, has maintained both its class and its 'Settings' option.

Would anyone know what's going on here and how I can bring back this class?